# How to join tables in rows instead of columns?

Tags: sql, join, view

I have some problems with creating a database view. I would like to join several tables to a single view. I would like to get each column as a row, instead of a column.

Here is a small example of two tables:

> **Tables**

```
| Table1: Id | Table1: Type |   | Table2: Id | Table2:Type |
|:----------:|:------------:|   |:----------:|:-----------:|
|      1     |       A      |   |      1     |      C      |
|      1     |       B      |   |      2     |      D      |
|      2     |       B      |   |      2     |      E      |
```

If I use following SQL statement, I get as expected following result:

> **SQL Statement**

```
SELECT
    table1.id,
    table1.Type AS Type1,
    table2.Type AS Type2
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

> **Result**

```
| Id    | Type1     | Type2     |
|:--:   |:-----:    |:-----:    |
|  1    |   A       |   C       |
|  1    |   B       |   C       |
|  2    |   B       |   D       |
|  2    |   B       |   E       |
```

I knew that this is correct. But I would like to get something like:

```
| Id    | Type      |
|:--:   |:-----:    |
|  1    |   A       |
|  1    |   B       |
|  1    |   C       |
|  2    |   B       |
|  2    |   D       |
|  2    |   E       |
```

This view displays for each `Id`, `Type` combination a single row.

How could I joind tables in that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, Type FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, Type FROM table2
ORDER BY ID,TYPE
```

Result:

```
ID  TYPE
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   B
2   D
2   E
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59d6b6/2).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, Type from table1
union all
SELECT id, Type from table2
order by id, type
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just add the order by without using a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
select id,type from table_name
UNION ALL
select id,type from table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Join multiple queries with the keyword `UNION ALL`. If you want to get rid of duplicate results, use `UNION`.

Make sure that the columns match in number and datatype.

Example:

```
SELECT id, Type from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, Type from table2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id,type from table1
union all
select id,type from table2
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp